# If every element in a finite monoid $(M, \star)$ is uniquely-regular then $M$ is a group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, monoid

Suppose that $(M, \star)$ is a finite Monoid and for every $m \in M$ there exists a unique element $n \in M$ such that $m\star n \star m=m$ or in other words every element in $M$ is (uniquely!) *regular*. Prove that $M$ is a  group.

I don't know where I should start from. I think $y$ must be the inverse of $x$ but I have no idea how to get there.

Answer (score 1):

From $mnm=m$ it follows $m(nmn)m=m$. Since $n$ is unique we get $nmn=n$. Therefore $M$ is an inverse semigroup. An example such a semigroup, not a group, is a semilattice, i.e.  an commutative idempotent semigroup (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semilattice#Algebraic_definition).

*Remark:* If you want to have a monoid, you can join an extra identity (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid#Examples) to the given semigroup.

Comment: I don't know what an inverse semi-group is unfortunately. Would you please explain why it can't be a group? Do you have any counter-examples in mind?

Comment: What is an inverse semi-group, you can find in any book on semigroups or in Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_semigroup). I expanded the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the expanded answer. But we are already in a finite Monoid. So the identity is already there in $M$. Doesn't that help us to prove $mn=nm=e$ in some way considering the fact that $M$ is a finite set and has an identity element?

Comment: No. There are finite semi-lattices (e.g. the power set of a finite set) in which the identity $mn=nm=e$ is not true.

Comment: Thank you Boris. You have really helped me today. Especially with proposing counter-examples. Even though I'm not familiar with semi-lattices yet. These problems are from my old homework exercises for Algebra I, that's why I'm not familiar with semi-groups and other stuff yet. I only know their definitions and some basic theorems.